# How can I override resources for Third-Party bundles in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I did a fresh Symfony installation by using Symfony Flex and the new skeleton belong to the next Symfony 4 directory structure. Next, [I'm going to override some resources](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/bundles/inheritance.html) like templates, translations, etc. from an external bundle.

I've tried to create all these paths for templates (to start) but nothing works:

- `templates/EasyAdminBundle/views/...`
- `templates/Resources/EasyAdminBundle/views/...`
- `app/Resources/...` (just a proof from old structure)

Where should I puts my resources files to override third-party bundle resources?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For all Symfony versions** the resources path is `%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/` . As the new 4.0 structure puts the `Kernel.php` into `src/` directory, then it is:

```
# local resources directory
src/Resources/
# still works this path for local templates
src/Resources/views/ 

# override resources for third-party bundles
src/Resources/AcmeDemoBundle/views/ # legacy convention to override templates
src/Resources/AcmeDemoBundle/translations/ # for override both translations and validations files
src/Resources/AcmeDemoBundle/... # etc.
```

#### New conventions to override resources (since Symfony 3.4)

**[Twig Templates](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/24179)**:
Just follow the convention:

```
templates/bundles/AcmeDemoBundle/path/to/template.html.twig
```

> If you are upgrading to Symfony 3.4 & 4.0 and you want to use the previous templates conventions, configure your own Twig's paths:
>
> ```
> # app/config/config.yml (3.3)
> twig:
>     paths:
>         # Default templates directory, since 3.4+
>         templates: ~
>
>         # Directory convention to override bundle templates, since 3.4+
>         # make sure to know the actual Twig namespace for each bundle.
>         # e.g. AcmeDemoBundle -> AcmeDemo:
>         templates/bundles/AcmeDemoBundle: AcmeDemo
> ```

[**Translations:**](http://symfony.com/doc/4.0/bundles/override.html#translations) Similar to `templates/` you have the `translations/` directory at the root of the project (by default):

```
translations/bundles/AcmeDemoBundle/messages.en.yml
```

Note: The `/bundles/AcmeDemoBundle/` sub-directory is **not** mandatory because translations are not related to bundles, but to domains. That means that you can override translations as long as it is in the correct domain.