# How to override bundle templates and controllers (FOSUserBundle) without using bundle inheritance

Tags: symfony, inheritance, fosuserbundle, symfony4

In my `Symfony 2.8` based project I use `FOSUserBundle` and extended it with a custom `MyUserBundle` using bundle inheritance.

When trying to update `FOSUserBundle` from 2.0.2 to 2.1.2 I came across several problems.

Since Bundle inheritance is deprecated in `Symfony 3.4` and completely dropped in `Symfony 4.0` I am now trying to achieve the same result without using bundle inheritance.

I found many information that shows, that bundle resources can be overridden by simply placing the files in the `app/Resources/<BundleName>/...`. Thus the `FOSUserBundle` templates could be overridden by placing them in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/<template.html.twig>`

While this will work, it does not deliver the same result as bundle inheritance. I can use my inherited bundle in different projects and thus reuse the same code over and over again. Using the `app/Resources/<BundleName>/...` solution would only work for the current project.

**Question 1:** How to override templates (and other resources) within a custom bundle which can be used in different projects rather than within a project specific `app/Resources` folder?

**Question 2:** How to override the behavior of controllers which to not offer event to to do so?

Currently I am using bundle inheritance to override the `confirmedAction` to send the user to a custom setup page rather than to the default page:

```
// Original FOSUserBundle code
public function confirmedAction(Request $request) {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/confirmed.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'targetUrl' => $this->getTargetUrlFromSession($request->getSession()),
    ));
}  


// MyUserBundle codes which should override the default behavior
public function confirmedAction(Request $request) {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    // Send user to setup-page
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_setup');
}
```

How can I control the behavior in the same way and send the user to a setup page instead of to the default confirmation page without using bundle inheritance?

As far as I know `FOSUserBundle` does not provide an option to specify the confirmation target. Of course I could intercept the request to the confirmed-route using some request event listener and re-route it. But this would be quite hacky. Would this be the right solution to do this or is there a cleaner way to achieve the same?

Comment: Q1: have you tried https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html#multiple-paths-per-namespace ?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239524/4224384 can help you partially to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Overriding resources within a bundle since Symfony 4.0 without bundle inheritance

**About Controllers**

Routes! is the way to achieve it now, "the first route found wins" so make sure to define the same route before the original one, with your custom controller. e.g.:

```
<route id="fos_user_registration_confirmed" path="/confirmed" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">MyUserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::confirmedAction</default>
</route>
```

Then, your routing file `MyUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml` must be imported before the `FOSUserBundle` routing file. This way, your custom action will be executed instead of the original `fos_user.registration.controller:confirmedAction`.

**About Templates**

Again, "the first template found wins" so make sure your bundle `views` path is defined before the one in `FOSUser` Twig namespace. You can achieve it by creating a [compiler pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-separate-compiler-passes):

```
// MyUserBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TwigPass.php

$path = dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/Resources/views';

$twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition = $container->findDefinition('twig.loader.native_filesystem');
$twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition->addMethodCall('prependPath', array($path, 'FOSUser'));
```

Check the Twig loader paths by running `bin/console debug:twig`, it should look like this:

```
  @FOSUser               - vendor/acme/my-user-bundle/Resources/views                                               
                         - vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views
```

From here, you're able to override any template of `FOSUserBundle` like `Registration/confirmed.html.twig` when `@FOSUser/Registration/confirmed.html.twig` is called.

Comment: Thanks! I get the message, that `twig.loader.native_filesystem` is a non-existing service? Is this only included in SF > 2.8 (which I am currently using)?

Comment: @AndreiHerford my bad, you should create a compiler pass instead to get and modify the `twig.loader.native_filesystem` service definition. Answer updated!